# Почему выдает false при сравнении одинаковых переменных? (Java)

Tags: java

```
String name = "material_";
String anotherName = "material_";
String x = "4";

if(anotherName == name){
    System.out.println(true);
}else{
    System.out.println(false);
}

name += x;
anotherName += x;

if(anotherName == name){
    System.out.println(true);
}else{
    System.out.println(false);
}
```

В первос сравнении выдает true , а при втором выдает flase.Я не понимаю почему после добавления 4 эти две переменные не равны.

[image: Вывод:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cравнивайте строки через `equals()` То есть:

```
if( anotherName.equals( name ) ) {
     doSomething( );
else {
     doSomethingElse( );
```

Оператор `==` не сравнивает не две строки, а две ссылки.

Comment: О точно спасибо большое)

Comment: @RuslanErdenoff если ответ вас удовлетворил, отметьте его как правильный